# Creating Dynamic column in Excel

Tags: excel

I am new to Excel and I trying to carry a complicated (for me) project. I would like to create a dynamic column in excel. Let me explain what I mean. Assume that in column A we have numbers 1,2,.. ,10, sitting on cells A1 through A10. In column B I want to get the squares of those numbers, i.e. in cell B1 to have 1, in B2 to have 4 ... in B10 to have 100. Squaring is just an example, it could be another more complicated function.

The problem is that I don't know how many numbers I will have at column A. I may have 10 numbers, I may have 200 numbers or 1000 numbers. I want the squares to be calculated automatically without me having to intervene at all. For example, in the example with numbers 1-10 above, if I add number 11 at A11, I want to get 121 at cell B11 automatically, without any intervention. Also, if I delete numbers 10 and 11, I want to get empty cells at B10 and B11, not zeros. I have done it in VBA, now I searching a way to do it in Excel directly. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I completely understand the question but it sounds like when a number is added to column A then Column B should automatically populate the squared number. 
The way I would handle this is create a table and enter a formula for column B.
When a record is added to the table (new cell in A) then the table will automatically add the formula.

Try this. 
Open your sheet. 
Highlight your columns.
Under the Home tab in the ribbon; select format as table.(Select if it has headers)
In the second column 
enter "=[@Column1]*[@Column1]" (without quotes)
or you can type the "=" and then select the 1st column, then "*" then select the column again. 
Now when you add a new row it will auto populate this formula and square the value in column one. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Oops just saw the no Zero part. Use this formula "=IF([@Column1]*[@Column1]=0,"")"

Comment: Thanks very much, it works when the columns are next to each other. But if they are not, I don't know if it is possible to create a table. I didn't know about tables (new to excel), so in the description of the problem I put the columns next to each other for simplicity; in my original problem they shouldn't be.

Comment: OK try this. Forget the table concept. Enter this formula in the column you want to show the square. Then select the cell and hit ctrl+Shift+down arrow, then hit ctrl+D this will fill the entire column with the formula.  The formula is =IF(A1*A1=0," ",A1*A1) this is assuming your number column is A.

Comment: Just a quick tutorial on the formula. Basically what it is saying is IF the value in A1 times itself is zero then this cell should be blank if not then it should contain the value of A1 times itself.